# unbound variable: geiser:no-values

Tags: emacs, geiser

The error occur when I execute `M-x geiser-mit` in emacs (which version is emacs-plus@29)

[image]

I've tried to `(restart 1)` as it mentioned.
But it seems just ignore the error.

The error indicate that I have to bound `geiser` a value.
But where and how?

I've tried `M-x geiser RET mit RET`, but still the same error.

Comment: `geiser:no-values` is defined in the `emacs.scm` library that is trying to compile when the repl starts up.  It looks like that compilation is failing for some reason, hence the unbound variable.  You should see a message  `Loading "emacs.com"...` near the end of repl initialization

Answer (score 0):

I tried on two mac, one (macos version: Monterey)succeeded, the other one(macos version:sonoma) failed like you did

screen print on succesfull one:

```
MIT/GNU Scheme running under OS X
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 2022 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Image saved on Saturday January 7, 2023 at 8:36:21 PM
  Release 12.1 || SF || LIAR/x86-64
;Loading "/Users/frankwu/.emacs.d/elpa/geiser-mit-20211204.1935/src/geiser/load.scm"...
;  Loading "compile.scm"...
;    Loading "make.com"...
;      Loading "cref-unx.pkd"... done
;      Loading "mset.com"... done
;      Loading "object.com"... done
;      Loading "toplev.com"... done
;      Loading "anfile.com"... done
;      Loading "conpkg.com"... done
;      Loading "forpkg.com"... done
;      Loading "redpkg.com"... done
;    ... done
;    Generating SCode for file: "emacs.scm" => "emacs.bin"... done
;    Compiling file: "emacs.bin" => "emacs.com"... done
;    Dumping "geiser-w32.pkd"... done
;    Dumping "geiser-unx.pkd"... done
;  ... done
;  Loading "geiser-unx.pkd"... done
;  Loading "emacs.com"...
;    Loading "format.com"... done
;  ... done
;... done
```

I compared the two logs

My conclusion:

```
   (cf "emacs")
```

in compile.scm  (cf "emacs") failed, then "geiser-unx.pkd" can not be found to load